HTML form through Google Sheets automatically getting marked as read by Airmail
I'm not tech-savvy. I followed this tutorial to set up an HTML form through Google Sheets. For some reason, the emails are automatically marked as "read" by Airmail, and I have no idea why. These emails are not automatically marked as read when viewing them through Gmail. I really don't want to switch email clients because of some weird Google routing or labeling issue. What could be the cause?

MailApp.sendEmail(emailRecipient, emailSubject, emailBody); - This is the line of code that is generating the recipient email. This service allows users to send emails with complete control over the content of the email. some weird Google routing or labeling issue - I think the problem is more likely to be in Airmail than MailApp.

Do you use a Gmail address, using AirMail as an e-mail client?

Thanks for getting back. Yes, I use a Gmail address and Airmail as a client.

So the problem is not as outlined in the question. The problem is that the script is sending an email from a given Gmail account to the same, given Gmail account. Gmail will automatically treat this as “read”. The goal is how to apply a workaround to “unread” the email (perhaps a filter based on the subject-just a shot in the dark). But the html form and Airmail are red herrings, or at least that’s my 2 cents worth.

That makes perfect sense. Thanks!
